# Why does transfer files to another computer by `sudo rsync` require the destination computer's root's password?

Tags: sudo, rsync, root

I am trying to transfer a directory to another computer

```
$ rsync -a --delete --stats -h wget 'olive:/tmp'

Number of files: 5 (reg: 4, dir: 1)
Number of created files: 5 (reg: 4, dir: 1)
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 4
Total file size: 12.94K bytes
Total transferred file size: 12.94K bytes
Literal data: 12.94K bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 13.31K
Total bytes received: 103

sent 13.31K bytes  received 103 bytes  5.36K bytes/sec
total size is 12.94K  speedup is 0.96
```

In case the source directory contains some files require local root permission, I add `sudo`. Is it correct?

But why does it keep asking me for the other computer's root's password? I provided the password of destination's root, but it keeps asking for it.

```
$ sudo rsync -a --delete --stats -h wget 'olive:/tmp'
root@olive's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@olive's password:
```

How shall I do if I want to copy source files that require local root permission?

I tried the suggested duplicate, but it didn't work

```
$ sudo rsync -e 'ssh -i /home/t/.ssh/id_rsa' -a --delete --stats -h wget 'olive:/tmp'
root@olive's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@olive's password:
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your last example, it looks like your non-root username is `t`.

When you use `ssh`, `scp` or `rsync` and don't specify a remote username, the tools will assume that the remote username is the same as the local one. So the command in your first example:

```
rsync -a --delete --stats -h wget 'olive:/tmp'
```

could be written more explicitly as:

```
rsync -a --delete --stats -h wget 't@olive:/tmp'
```

When you prefix the command with `sudo`, it changes the username the rest of the command line is executed as (to `root`, unless `sudo -u <username>` is used).

So, your second example:

```
sudo rsync -a --delete --stats -h wget 'olive:/tmp'
```

is now equivalent to:

```
sudo rsync -a --delete --stats -h wget 'root@olive:/tmp'
```

because the `rsync` command is being run as root, and since remote username is not defined, it assumes you want to perform the rsync operation using the root account at the remote side too.

---

Fix: When using `rsync` with `sudo`, be explicit about the remote username you'll want to use:

```
sudo rsync -a --delete --stats -h wget 't@olive:/tmp'
```

or if that does not work (i.e. your `sudo` is configured with the `always_set_home` option enabled so it changes the `$HOME` environment variable for commands executed with it to match the user the command is going to be run as), then try this form of your third example:

```
sudo rsync -e 'ssh -i /home/t/.ssh/id_rsa' -a --delete --stats -h wget 't@olive:/tmp'
```

In this form, the `rsync` command executes locally as `root`, but logs onto `olive` as user `t` - which seems to have the SSH keys set up according to your first example.

No, the username does not *have* to be the same on both ends of a `rsync` (or `scp`!) operation - omitting the remote username is just a shorthand for the common situations when the username *is* the same.

Comment: Thanks. Does `sudo rsync -a --delete --stats -h wget 'olive:/tmp'` also look for public key file for `root` which is local `/.ssh/id_rsa`?

Comment: Depends on settings of your `sudo` command - if it has the `always_set_home` option set, it will change the `$HOME` variable, and then the default SSH key is classically `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa` = `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` or whatever. But if that `sudo` option is not set, then your `sudo <command>` will execute the command as root but with `$HOME` still set to `/home/t`. The longest form of the command specifies both the remote username and the location of the private key to use explicitly - and since the local end of `rsync` runs as root, accessing that key is presumably no problem at all.

Comment: Thanks. When running `sudo rsync -a --delete --stats -h wget 'olive:/tmp'`, why does it keep asking me the password of the target machine's root password, after I have provided it? Does ssh need it  every time it transfer a file? Or did I not provide the correct password?

Comment: Either the password was wrong, or the target system's `sshd` is not allowing direct root logins with password authentication, and it's just going through the motions of asking for the password and rejecting the attempts *anyway*, in order to make a potential intruder waste their time with useless password-guessing attempts. To find out which it is, you'll need to get to view the remote server's log - and that will usually require either a *successful* login, or talking to the server's administrator, who can presumably tell whether your question is legitimate or not.

Comment: Thanks. I install sshd (opensshd?) on the target machine, and the configuration is default (I have never modified it). I know the password of root on the target machine. How shall I view the remote server's log?

Comment: At least on Debian/Ubuntu distributions, the default setting for `PermitRootLogin` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is `prohibit-password`, i.e. direct root logins are allowed by SSH key authentication only. To view the authentication/security-related logs once logged into the remote system, you might use `sudo less /var/log/auth.log` on Debian/Ubuntu or their relatives, or `sudo less /var/log/secure` on RedHat/SuSE-style systems.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on by what account you are running the rsync command as. If you run as root then it expects you have root privileges on the destination system

Comment: Or rather "it expects that you'd want to log in as the root user, since you did not explicitly say what other user you wanted to log in as".